# SQL-Pandas : transform with Sum on past and new data

Tags: sql, pandas

I have some user records in xlsx file and I am storing those records in SQL Database by applying some **groupby-transform-Sum() functionality of pandas** if there multiple instances for particular combination monthly basis (Exa. Id-Location-Designation-Day-PolicySold)

Until now all of the past and newly added data used to maintained in xlsx file only, but moving on only recent 3 months data will be available and I need to store this new data into SQL Db ensuring past data which is already present in SQL DB( for several months,years) intact and ensuring no duplicate entries .

Can anyone suggest me efficient approach to handle this?

My current approach is : 
1. Read the past data from SQL table before performing new write operation.
2. Read new data from xlsx.
3. Merge both
4. Apply Groupby.transformation with Sum() to convert daily to monthly data